# How to use the IN operator in sqlite3 with parameters?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-db-api

Python 3.5.2, stdlib sqlite3.

I'm trying to issue a SQL query with a dynamic criterion in an `IN` operator in the `WHERE` clause:

#### bad code (doesn't work)

```
def top_item_counts_in_installations(cursor, installation_names):
    return cursor.execute(
        "SELECT itm.name, COUNT(*)"
        " FROM Installations ins INNER JOIN Items itm ON itm.id=ins.itmid"
        " WHERE ins.name IN (?)"
        " GROUP BY itm.name"
        " ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC"
        " LIMIT 3",
        (installation_names,))
```

`installation_names` is a tuple, but the above does not work, obviously, with an error

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

So what I currently do is prepare a sequence of parameter holders based on the length of `installation_names`:

#### kludge (working but ugly)

```
def top_item_counts_in_installations(cursor, installation_names):
    param_holders= ",".join("?" for i in installation_names)
    return cursor.execute(
        "SELECT itm.name, COUNT(*)"
        " FROM Installations ins INNER JOIN Items itm ON itm.id=ins.itmid"
        " WHERE ins.name IN (%s)"
        " GROUP BY itm.name"
        " ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC"
        " LIMIT 3" % param_holders,
        installation_names)
```

Is there a proper way to parameterize the right term of `IN` instead of my kludge? I haven't managed to find something in the documentation.

Comment: I don't think there's anything much better than that solution. You could convert the list into a regular expression and then use `REGEXP`

Comment: @Barmar Now that is in interesting idea, with the only extra implication of making sure that the items in `installation_names` are properly escaped for `REGEXP` purposes.

Comment: `re.escape()` will do that.

Comment: There's not really any advantage to a regexp - you still need to generate it and make sure it's escaped and then you lose any optimisation the planner can do re: indexes/hash lookups etc... Anyway - your second example is the canonical way to do it... Unless you switch to using an ORM.

Comment: @JonClements then you should make your comment into an answer so I can “bless” it and close this question for posterity :)